# Codeigniter - Using Userdata for DB Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to use Session data as a condition for a query in database, but it only returns NULL. I have tried $this->session->userdata('account'), but it still won't work.

Function - Login/Set Userdata :

```
    public function login_auth()
  {
        $this->load->helper('security');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
                $this->dashboard();
            }else{
                $this->index();
            }
        } else {
            $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );
            $result = $this->agent_model->login($data);
            if ($result == TRUE) {
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $result = $this->agent_model->read_user_information($username);
                if ($result != false) {
                    $session_data = array(
                    'username' => $result[0]->username,
                    'owner' => $result[0]->owner,
                    'account' => $result[0]->account,
                    'id' => $result[0]->id
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
                    $this->dashboard();
                }
            } else {
                $data = array(
                'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
                );
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('pages/login', $data);
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }
        }
  }
```

Function - Using Userdata->Account as a condition(From Another Function)

```
$sess_account = $this->session->userdata('account');
    var_dump($this->session->userdata('account'));
    $coords = $this->map_model->get_coordinates($sess_account);
```

Am i missing something here? Any help is truly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We need more information. First, how are you setting that session data value? Can you post that line of code? Plus, you can see what is in session by checking $_SESSION values. Example: var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: can you put this somplace in your code and show us the output? `print "<pre>".print_r($this->session(), true)."</pre>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that the session item 'logged_in' should have been set and `$this->session->userdata['logged_in']` is returning `null` it is likely you do not have `session` configured correctly.

It's almost always improper `$config` value for session and or cookie items.

[Here is a git repo](https://github.com/dafriend/Codeigniter-Session-Tester) that should help you test your setup.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out that i had a typo on a config. Fixed it!